# django form not submitting when rendering specific fields in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have an UpdateUserForm:

```
class UserUpdateForm(UserChangeForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput())
    last_login = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'hidden'}))
    is_superuser = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'type': 'hidden'}))
    is_staff = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'type': 'hidden'}))
    is_active = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'type': 'hidden'}))
    date_joined = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'hidden'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'last_login', 'date_joined')

    def update_user_notification(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if self.is_valid():
            update_user_notification_task.delay(email, username)
```

and a UserUpdate view:

```
class UserUpdate(generic.UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserUpdateForm
    template_name = 'accounts/update_user.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save()
        form.update_user_notification()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user_detail', args=[str(instance.pk)]))
```

I originally wrote this form in the template as `{{form.as_p}}` and it worked, but there were some things I wanted to fix:

```
<h1>Update Information...</h1>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button>UPDATE</button>
</form>

<br></br>
<a href="{% url 'user_detail' user.pk %}">Back</a>
<a href="/">Home</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Rendered as this:

[image]

I wanted to get rid of those password related things at the bottom so I changed my form to:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><label>{{form.email.label}}: </label>{{form.email}}</p>
    <p><label>{{form.username.label}}: </label>{{form.username}}</p>
    <p><label>{{form.first_name.label}}: </label>{{form.first_name}}</p>
    <p><label>{{form.last_name.label}}: </label>{{form.last_name}}</p>
    <button>UPDATE</button>
</form>
```

This worked on the frontend, but now my form isn't submitting. When I click update, the page looks as if it's loading, but my database doesn't updating and my celery task isn't run. What's the issue?

Do I need to have all the fields in order to submit the form? Is there a way to just exclude the password related fields? And is that a better option?

Comment: Does your form throw any errors or does it validate? Might be that you're missing the User ID in the form or something

Comment: no errors. I hit update, get a 200 ok, but no actual update

Comment: @Eddy please provide us with a view. It seems, you work wrong with post. Save (change delete update) - happens on post, in GCBV on form_valid. If nothing changes - it means you save nothing. That's why it is important to see, how you save something.

Comment: added view for user update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was actually really simple. I added `{{form.errors}}` to see if any errors were occurring in the actual form, since there were no errors in my network tab.

Turns out that `last_login` and `date_joined` are both required in order to POST the form. Once I added them in:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><label>{{form.email.label}}: </label>{{form.email}}</p>
    <p><label>{{form.username.label}}: </label>{{form.username}}</p>
    <p><label>{{form.first_name.label}}: </label>{{form.first_name}}</p>
    <p><label>{{form.last_name.label}}: </label>{{form.last_name}}</p>
    <p>{{form.last_login}}</p>
    <p>{{form.date_joined}}</p>
    <button>UPDATE</button>
</form>
```

The form was able to submit and update the database. I left out the label because those forms for me are `attrs={'type': 'hidden'}` anyway. Although this brings up another question as to why are these fields required to submit? Is there a way to just not require them and save the trouble of hiding them?